# Зачем в таком случае сохранять Presenter сериализацией

Tags: android, mvp

При повороте экрана, некий фоновый процесс может быть завершен и потребуется отобразить результат. В таком случае презентер вообще не убивают, а к новой вью применяют последние события. (Подход от `Moxy`) 
Другой случай, когда вью умирает и сохраняет состояние презентера.

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        PresenterManager.getInstance().savePresenter(presenter, outState);
    }
```

Такой подход подразумевает, что мы не будем ничего отображать по завершению фоновых операций или  таких операций вовсе нет. 
 
И вот вопрос. А зачем сохранять в таком случае презентер ? Что в нем может быть такого, что стоит сохранить? Ведь презентер это всего лишь посредник. Скажете, что  вью в этот момент мог  отображать загруженный список( с чем-то), сам список лежит в презентере. Но я отвечу: Список можно хранить вне презентера, убрать эту лишнюю ответственность с презентера и вынести в отдельный класс, которому и надо будет обеспечить сохранение. 
Ну я понимаю, что в  обучающих статьях, сохраняя презентер, имеется ввиду сохранение состояния презентера, но чтобы не усложнять не пишут о том, что состояние презентера нужно хранить вне презентера.  Тем не менее я ищу еще причины по которым стоит сохранять презентер, может что то ускользнуло от моего внимания.
Сохранение ссылок на `DataManager` тоже не нужно, если использовать Инъекцию зависимостей.